# iOS >> Local Notifications >> How to Connect a Local Notification a Specific Object?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, data-objects

In my app I keep an array of data objects; upon certain actions, a Data Object is creating a Local Notification. I wish to have the Local Notification be able to recognise the Object that created it, so when the user opens the notification - whether it's from a UIAlertView that pops if the Notification is fired when the app is active, or whether it's triggered by the Notification view that pops when the app is in the background - I can open a screen with the specific Object Data presented.

How do I define for a Local Notification instance a relevant Object of mine?

Comment: use `Notif.userinfo` property of notification. It will take a dictionary for save object. You can get this in Receive Notification method by Notif.userinfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way...

NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YOUR OBJECT" forKey:@"YOUR KEY"];

```
   UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.fireDate = Pre_date;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [txtRemindetText text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotif.userInfo=dict;
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    // Handle the notificaton when the app is running
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);
    NSLog(@"%@",notif.userInfo);
    NSLog(@"%@",[notif.userInfo objectForKey:@"YOUR KEY"];
}
```

**Let me know if you have any problem.**